# Can't set a custom contextmenu to a table in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, richtextbox

```xml
<Window.Resources>
  <ContextMenu x:Key="TableContextMenu">
   <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
   <MenuItem Header="asdasdsad" />
  </ContextMenu>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Table}">
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TableContextMenu}" />
  </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, you have to manually open the contextmenu ..

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TableCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="Table_ContextMenuOpening" />
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TableContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
```

In the contextmenu opening handler you have to set the handled param to true and open the contextmenu

```
lastTableCell.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

If your commands in the  contextmenu are grayed out: afaik this is a bug and you have to put your command bindings directly into the contextmenu in XAML

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TableContextMenu">
        <ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static main:MainWindow.AddRowAboveCommand}"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteAlways"
                    Executed="AddRowAbove_Executed" />
        </ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
```

Cheers

Comment: Got this answer in msdn forums .. don't know if this works

    richtextbox.IsDocumentEnabled="true"